# Add different prefix to index by column value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reindex

I have a dataframe, with duplicated index, which I'm trying to reindex according to rowname of another dataframe. However, due to the duplicated index problem it's telling me `cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels` when I do `df2 = df2.reindex(df.index)`.

Below is what my df2 looks like

| index | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | sample_a | 1 |
| B | sample_a | 3 |
| B | sample_b | 2 |
| C | sample_c | 3 |

So I want to make my index unique by adding prefix to it by values from column1. If column1 is sample_a, I want to make index as a_index; if column1 is sample_b, I want to change index as b_index, to change my df2 as below:

| index | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a_A | sample_a | 1 |
| a_B | sample_a | 3 |
| b_B | sample_b | 2 |
| c_C | sample_c | 3 |

I do see ways of adding prefix to index but I'm not sure how to selectively add different prefix?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your other DataFrame also has both "index" and "column1", why not use both as index?

Alternatively, you can de-duplicate "index" using [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get the id from "column1" that is after the underscore:

```
df['index'] = (df['column1']
                 .str.extract('_([^_]+)$', expand=False)
                 .add('_'+df['index'])
              )
```

Updated dataframe:

```
  index   column1  column2
0   a_A  sample_a        1
1   a_B  sample_a        3
2   b_B  sample_b        2
3   c_C  sample_c        3
```

regex:

```
_        # match underscore
([^_]+)  # capture non-underscore characters
$        # match end of line
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wJRY86/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.slice`

```
df2['index'] = df2['column1'].str.slice(-1) + "_" + df2['index']
```

##### Output:

```
  index   column1  column2
0   a_A  sample_a        1
1   a_B  sample_a        3
2   b_B  sample_b        2
3   c_C  sample_c        3
```

##### As a side note:

You can also guarantee a unique index by using pandas dataframe [.cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

Like this:

```
df2['index'] = df2['index'] + df2.groupby(['index'])['index'].cumcount().astype(str)
```

Which produces this kind of output:

```
  index   column1  column2
0    A0  sample_a        1
1    B0  sample_a        3
2    B1  sample_b        2
3    C0  sample_c        3
```

Comment: You should note that this assumes single characters after the underscore ;)

Comment: Correct - this is true.